# How do i keep image on transparent background?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio, gridview

[I want to acheive the following. Transparent background with white tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0JVh.png)
How do i get the white tick mark on the transparent background. 
i tried the following.

```
viewprev = mgridview.getChildAt(i - mgridview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                viewprev.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                viewprev.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: viewprev.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMain"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="#99676767"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivMain"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivMain">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_favorite" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Your tick should be in the `FrameLayout` which should be constrainted as in the code so its always in the middle of the `ImageView`. From the image I guess you're trying to create a long click to select items kind of thing. If so just set the visibility of `FrameLayout` to `gone` in xml and in LongClick event set it to `visible`

This is the output of above code:

[image: output]

You can play around with the color to achieve your desired transparency level

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use FrameLayout.The Framelayout contains your image and an empty ImageView above it. When you need to draw a tick - just set its image into that ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an `ImageView` to your grid item layout. Remember to insert the xml tag below the main grid image in order to appear on top. Then use `match_parent` as the image view width and height and assign the `scaleType` to center. This is your check mark view. You can add a semi transparent background to make a shade above the grid item image and the `src` attribute goes to the check mark.

You can also modify the image view visibility toggle hide and show of the check mark item.